# How to make taskbar not on top in Win7?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-7

How to make taskbar not on top in Win7 using C/C++? Actually, the case is I have two applications. One of them is in fullscreen. Then if I want to open the dialog of the second app, I see the taskbar on top of the first application. 
Also, even if I make the window of the second app the child of first app window, it doesn't work. I mean, I have a fullscreen window and then I focus on the second app window, taskbar appears.

Comment: I don't think it's something that could be easily changed.

Comment: On the one hand, taskbar is a window like other, so it can be both above and beyond. On the other hand, it is on top by design. You can only temporary get above that - it will climb up back e.g. with `Win` key pressed.

Comment: @RomanR. So it's just impossible to do?

Comment: You should be able to make the taskbar auto-hide. At least, the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1381821/56778) indicate that you can.

Comment: What about setting the auto-hide property on start-up and clearing it again on exit? You could easily include a checkbox to enable such an option. I'd suppose it (the auto-hide property) to be stored in a registry key - one you could capture changes to, and therefore identify with RegMon.

Comment: @JimMischel - ha, too funny! 6 hours of inactivity, then two of us post the same thing within a minute..

Comment: @JimMischel No, unfortunatelly, that solution doesn't work for me.